# Delphi - how can I upload picture with drag & drop?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I tried to build an app to upload some data into website. Everything is okay but in the last fill is a  picture upload to `input type=file`. I tried a lot code from everywhere but I failed because I do not understand HTTP and it's complicated like this code:

```
procedure PostToURL(URL: OleVariant; EncodedStr, FileName: String);
var
  i: Integer;
  Post, Header: OleVariant;
  rez: String;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  // preberemo binarno datoteko
  FileStream:=TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  Try
   SetLength(Rez, FileStream.Size);
         FileStream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(Rez)^, FileStream.Size);
   Finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;

  // The post must be an array. But without null terminator (-1)
  Post := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(EncodedStr) - 1], varByte);

  // Put Post in array
  for I := 1 to Length(EncodedStr) do
    Post[I - 1] := Ord(EncodedStr[I]);

  Header := 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------ZcpvRS7HNeFzxVsIlOwdUo'+#13#10+#13#10+#13#10;
  // enako z ali brez tega
  //Header := Header+'------------ZcpvRS7HNeFzxVsIlOwdUo' + #13#10;
  //Header := Header+'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"' + #13#10 + #13#10;
  //Header := Header+'3072000'+#13#10;
  Header := Header+'----------ZcpvRS7HNeFzxVsIlOwdUo' + #13#10;
  Header := Header+'content-disposition: form-data; name="ThisFile" filename="'+ExtractFileName(FileName)+'"'+#13#10;
  Header := Header+'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' + #13#10;
  Header := Header+'Content-size: '+IntToStr(1) + #13#10; // GetFileSize(FileName)
  Header := Header+'Content-Type: image/bmp' + #13#10 + #13#10;
  Header := Header+ Rez + #13#10;
  Header := Header+'------------ZcpvRS7HNeFzxVsIlOwdUo' + #13#10;
  Header := Header+'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"' + #13#10 + #13#10;
  Header := Header+ 'Upload' + #13#10;
  Header := Header+'----------ZcpvRS7HNeFzxVsIlOwdUo--';
  WebMANForm.WebBrowser1.Navigate2(URL, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, Post, Header);
end;
```

The HTML code is:

```
                    </td>
<td rowspan="5" class="requestphoto">
<img id="image" runat="server" src="addOmraVisa_files/GetImage.png" height="150px" width="150px">
<div class="t-widget t-upload"><div class="t-dropzone"><div class="t-button t-upload-button"><span>... استعراض</span><input autocomplete="off" id="PersonalPhoto" name="PersonalPhoto" type="file"></div><em>drop files here to upload</em></div></div>
<br>
</td>
```

And in last HTML page the code like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#EmbbasyCode').tDropDownList({data:[{"Text":"","Value":""},{"Text":"تونس","Value":"303"}], index:1});
jQuery('#PersonalPhoto').tUpload({multiple:false, showFileList:false, async:{"saveUrl":"/Omra/SaveOmraPersonalPhoto","removeUrl":"/Omra/RemovePersonalPhoto","autoUpload":true}, onSuccess:OnSuccess, onError:OnError, onRemove:OnRemove, localization:{"cancel":"إلغاء","retry":"Retry","select":"... استعراض","remove":"Remove","uploadSelectedFiles":"Upload files","dropFilesHere":"drop files here to upload","statusFailed":"failed","statusUploaded":"uploaded","statusUploading":"uploading"}});
jQuery('#COMING_THROUGH').tDropDownList({data:[{"Text":"جوا","Value":"2"},{"Text":"برا","Value":"1"},{"Text":"بحرا","Value":"3"},{"Text":"مفتوح","Value":"4"}]});});
```

I want to change to drag & drop I think it's easier than HTTP. I see 
[Delphi: Simulating a drag and drop from the clipboard to EmbeddedWB’s IHTMLElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905373/delphi-simulating-a-drag-and-drop-from-the-clipboard-to-embeddedwb-s-ihtmleleme)
But I want to hide the browser in the run time without the user seeing anything so,
can any one help me? How can I fix the big problem please...
Let's say I have editor and a browser (twebbrowser or TEmbeddedWB)
edit.text = full picture path and button when click button picture upload 
from path in edit to dropzone...
Thanks.

Comment: Look at [Indy's](http://www.indyproject.org) `TIdHTTP` component. It has an overloaded `Post()` method that takes a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` as input. For the drag&drop, you can use Anders Melander's [Drag and Drop component suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/). So, the user can drop onto your app window, then you can extract the dropped data, `Add` it to the stream, and `Post` it to the target URL